# Achieving a persistence effect in GLKit view

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es

I have a GLKit view set up to draw a solid shape, a line and an array of points which all change every frame. The basics of my `drawInRect` method are:

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClear(...);
    glBufferData(...);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

    // draw solid shape
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);

    // draw line
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, ...);

    // draw points
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...);
}
```

This works fine; each array contains around 2000 points, but my iPad seems to have no problem rendering it all at 60fps.

The issue now is that I would like the lines to fade away slowly over time, instead of disappearing with the next frame, making a persistence or phosphor-like effect. The solid shape and the points must not linger, only the line.

I've tried the brute-force method (as used in Apple's example project aurioTouch): storing the data from the last 100 frames and drawing all 100 lines every frame, but this is too slow. My iPad can't render more than about 10fps with this method.

So my question is: can I achieve this more efficiently using some kind of frame or render buffer which accumulates the color of previous frames? Since I'm using GLKit, I haven't had to deal directly with these things before, and so don't know much about them. I've read about accumulation buffers, which seem to do what I want, but I've heard that they are very slow and anyway I can't tell whether they even exist in OpenGL ES 3, let alone how to use them.

I'm imagining something like the following (after setting up some kind of storage buffer):

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClear(...);
    glBufferData(...);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

    // draw solid shape
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);

    // draw contents of storage buffer

    // draw line
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, ...);

    // multiply the alpha value of each pixel in the storage buffer by 0.9 to fade

    // draw line again, this time into the storage buffer

    // draw points
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...);
}
```

Is this possible? What are the commands I need to use (in particular, to combine the contents of the storage buffer and change its alpha)? And is this likely to actually be more efficient than the brute-force method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up achieving the desired result by rendering to a texture, as described for example [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/). The basic idea is to setup a custom framebuffer and attach a texture to it – I then render the line that I want to persist into this framebuffer (without clearing it) and render the whole framebuffer as a texture into the default framebuffer (which is cleared every frame). Instead of clearing the custom framebuffer, I render a slightly opaque quad over the whole screen to make the previous contents fade out a little every frame.

The relevant code is below; setting up the framebuffer and persistence texture is done in the `init` method:

```
    // vertex data for fullscreen textured quad (x, y, texX, texY)
    GLfloat persistVertexData[16] = {-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                 -1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                                 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                                 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    // setup texture vertex buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &persistVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, persistVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(persistVertexData), persistVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // create texture for persistence data and bind
    glGenTextures(1, &persistTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, persistTexture);

    // provide an empty image
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 2048, 1536, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    // set texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // create frame buffer for persistence data
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &persistFrameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, persistFrameBuffer);

    // attach render buffer
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, persistTexture, 0);

    // check for errors
    NSAssert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, @"Error: persistence framebuffer incomplete!");

    // initialize default frame buffer pointer
    defaultFrameBuffer = -1;
```

and in the `glkView:drawInRect:` method:

```
// get default frame buffer id
if (defaultFrameBuffer == -1)
    glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &defaultFrameBuffer);

// clear screen
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


// DRAW PERSISTENCE

// bind persistence framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, persistFrameBuffer);

// render full screen quad to fade
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, persistVertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glUniform4f(colorU, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

// add most recent line
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataVertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glUniform4f(colorU, color[0], color[1], color[2], 0.8*color[3]);
glDrawArrays(...);

// return to normal framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFrameBuffer);

// switch to texture shader
glUseProgram(textureProgram);

// bind texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, persistTexture);
glUniform1i(textureTextureU, 0);

// set texture vertex attributes
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, persistVertexBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texturePositionA);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureTexCoordA);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.shaderBridge.texturePositionA, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(self.shaderBridge.textureTexCoordA, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(GLfloat), 2*sizeof(GLfloat));

// draw fullscreen quad with texture
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);


// DRAW NORMAL FRAME

glUseProgram(normalProgram);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);

// draw solid shape
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, ...);

// draw line
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, ...);

// draw points
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, ...);
```

The texture shaders are very simple: the vertex shader just passes the texture coordinate to the fragment shader:

```
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = aPosition;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

and the fragment shader reads the fragment color from the texture:

```
uniform highp sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);
}
```

Although this works, it doesn't seem very efficient, causing the renderer utilization to rise to close to 100%. It only seems better than the brute force approach when the number of lines drawn each frame exceeds 100 or so. If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve this code, I would be very grateful!